# Is half the log loss, twice as good?

Tags: loss-functions, logarithm, scoring-rules, log-loss

Lets say I have two different models based on the same dataset.

- Model A has a log loss of 0.30 on this dataset.
- Model B has a log loss of 0.60 on this dataset.

If our scoring metric is log loss, is it correct to say that Model A is twice as good as Model B? I guess I'm just not sure what scale log loss is based on (linear, logarithmic, something more exotic, etc.).

Comment: Here's a related question you might want to ponder. Despite its [drawbacks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787), let's consider classification accuracy. Is it more of an improvement to increase the accuracy from $50\%$ to $60\%$ or to increase the accuracy from $90\%$ to $99\%?$ What about $50\%$ to $75\%$ vs $90\%$ to $95\%?$

Comment: The minimal possible log loss is zero, so in a sense 0.3 is "twice as good" as 0.6. I don't really see how thinking in such terms is very useful, though...

Comment: If you have a situation where a small improvement to log loss can be made but the process is computationally expensive. Say going from 0.3000 to 0.2999. Having a more direct feel for the scale that log loss sits on might be helpful in making that decision.